# JavaScript "Object Method"

Tags: javascript, function, object, methods

```
  function Money(bill, accu, hb, food, webHosting, lynda) {
  Money.bill = bill;
  Money.accu = accu;
  Money.hb = hb;
  Money.food = food;
  Money.webHosting = webHosting;
  Money.lynda = lynda;
  Money.total = function () {
  (Money.bill + Money.accu + Money.hb + Money.food + Money.webHosting +    Money.lynda)
    return Money.total;
  };
}
var cost = new Money(2500, 5000, 2000, 6000, 1000, 30000);
 Money.total();
```

I have defined everything for a object using a variable at the end.
When I run Money.total(the "money" objects method) it returns as ""function""
Please help.I want the total of everything.

Comment: because you are returning the function `Money.total`..., your line above that, that does the actual math just does the math and then does nothing else with it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `this` instead of `Money' to read/write properties of the newly created object:

```
function Money(bill, accu, hb, food, webHosting, lynda) {
  this.bill = bill;
  this.accu = accu;
  this.hb = hb;
  this.food = food;
  this.webHosting = webHosting;
  this.lynda = lynda;
  this.total = function() {
      return this.bill + this.accu + this.hb + this.food + this.webHosting + this.lynda;
  }
}
```

It's unclear what you were trying to do with your 'total' method.  If you can describe what that is supposed to do, then we could help with that implementation, but I've provided an implementation that sums the properties.

Comment: @JokerSpirit - Did this answer your question?  Since it looks like you are perhaps new to StackOverflow, are you aware that if you get your question answered, then you should select the best answer and click the green checkmark to the left of the answer.  This will inform the community that your question has been answered and earn both you and the person supplying the answer with some reputation points.